# Specifying implementation at deploy time in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

This issue specifically stems from specifying an XMLOutputFactory implementation in a grails app, but I was looking for a more generic grails way to do this. So here goes.

In our grails app, we use the XMLOutputFactory to build XMLWriters that render out documents. Now the XMLOutputFactory implementation that we were looking for is present in the Sun's implementation of this class which is com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl.

So to use this, we added it as a system property in Glassfish, which we use as our app server and that works as we expect it be. Which leads me to my question(s), how would we have this mapping within the Grails app such that we don't need to update a server property for this.

Initially I thought it should be just adding it to the Config.groovy, but I don't think system properties are the same as grails config properties.

The second option was to call these at command time with the -D param. And that works, but I was looking for a more elegant solution to this.

Therefore, is there a "grails" way to do this? And if so, would those properties persist once deployed into the container? Or is updating the container properties the sole way to get around this.

I hope this makes sense :).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this configuration changes for deployments `Config.groovy` is a good place to put it, because you can [externalize it](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized), so in your server environment you can replace the value of the config.

*Config.groovy*

```
application.xmlFactory=...

grails.config.locations = [classpath:external-config.groovy]
```

*external-config.groovy*

```
application.xmlFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl
```

Comment: So I had tried this. But it seems like grails attaches this to the config properties, instead of java system properties that can be accessed using System.getProperty(...). I am thinking that the classloader doesn't quite look at grails config properties for something like this?